# Wordpress - Display Content Conditionally

Tags: wordpress, plugins, conditional-statements

I am fairly new to Wordpress.  I am writing a real estate site, and I want to have a Service Area page that displays the Counties that we serve in various states.  So what I want to happen is to have a dropdown list where a user can select a state, and based on the state that they select, a text area will display that counties that we service in that state.

So basically, I want to store text content in the form of counties that will be displayed based on the conditions of a dropdown list.

I have no idea where to start.  Is there a plugin that works for this kind of situation such as a form plugin that can store content, or am I going to have to write custom PHP/Javascript to make something like this happen.  I am asking because this seems like a common scenario on websites, I just don't know where to look.

Thanks for any suggestions that you may have!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was creating a select box in html that when a change happened on the list, a javascript function was called that changed the visibility of a text area and also set the value of its content to display all the counties that I needed.  Ended up being much more simple than I expected.  No PHP functions and short code necessary.